# How to create a ranking variable/function for different periods in a panel data?

Tags: python, pandas, ranking-functions

I have a dataset, `df`, that looks like this:

| Date | Code | City | State | Population | Quantity | QTDPERCAPITA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5000000 | 100000 | 0.02 |
| 2020-02 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5000000 | 125000 | 0.025 |
| 2020-03 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5000000 | 135000 | 0.027 |
| 2020-01 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3000000 | 150000 | 0.05 |
| 2020-02 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3000000 | 100000 | 0.033 |
| 2020-03 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3000000 | 200000 | 0.066 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5500499 | 340000 | 0.062 |
| 2021-07 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3250012 | 211000 | 0.065 |

Where`QTDPERCAPITA` is simply `Quantity/Population`. I have multiple cities (4149 to be more precise).

The quantities change according to every month, and so does the population.

I would like to create a new variable that serve as a ranking, ranging from `[0,1]`, where `0` is the city with the lowest `QTDPERCAPITA` in that month, and `1` is the city with the most quantity per capita in that month. Essentially, I want to create a new column that looks like this:

| Date | Code | City | State | Population | Quantity | QTDPERCAPITA | RANKING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5000000 | 100000 | 0.02 | 0 |
| 2020-02 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5000000 | 125000 | 0.025 | 0 |
| 2020-03 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5000000 | 135000 | 0.027 | 0 |
| 2020-01 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3000000 | 150000 | 0.05 | 1 |
| 2020-02 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3000000 | 100000 | 0.033 | 1 |
| 2020-03 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3000000 | 200000 | 0.066 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5500499 | 340000 | 0.062 | 0 |
| 2021-07 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3250012 | 211000 | 0.065 | 1 |

How can I create this column such that the `RANKING` changes every month? I was thinking of a `for` loop that extracts the `QTDPERCAPITA` for every city on every unique date, and creates a new column, `df['RANKING']` with the same `date` and `city`.

Comment: For (2021-07, LA), your QTDPERCAPITA is 0.618 for input and 0.062 for output. -> I fixed your post. Please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
# MinMax scaler: (rank - min) / (max - min)
ranking = lambda x: (x.rank() - 1) / (len(x) - 1)

# Rank between [0, 1] -> 0 the lowest, 1 the highest
df['RANKING'] = df.groupby('Date')['QTDPERCAPITA'].apply(ranking)

# Rank between [1, 4149] -> 1 the lowest, 4149 the highest
# df['RANKING'] = df.groupby('Date')['QTDPERCAPITA'].rank('dense')
```

Output:

| Date | Code | City | State | Population | Quantity | QTDPERCAPITA | RANKING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5000000 | 100000 | 0.02 | 0 |
| 2020-02 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5000000 | 125000 | 0.025 | 0 |
| 2020-03 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5000000 | 135000 | 0.027 | 0 |
| 2020-01 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3000000 | 150000 | 0.05 | 1 |
| 2020-02 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3000000 | 100000 | 0.033 | 1 |
| 2020-03 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3000000 | 200000 | 0.066 | 1 |
| 2021-07 | 11001 | Los Angeles | CA | 5500499 | 340000 | 0.618 | 1 |
| 2021-07 | 12002 | Houston | TX | 3250012 | 211000 | 0.065 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
# get unique values for each month
months = list(set(df['Date'].values))

# initialze a new column the length of our dataframe
rank_col = [None] * 9

for month in months:
  # get all the QTDPERCAPITA values for current month
  month_qtdpc = df[df['Date'] == month]['QTDPERCAPITA']

  # normalize such that best city has 1 and worst has 0 for this month
  max = month_qtdpc.max()
  min = month_qtdpc.min()
  rankings = (month_qtdpc - min) / (max - min)

  # insert each rank value at the proper index in our list 
  for i, rank in rankings.iteritems(): 
    rank_col[i] = rank

# add it as a column to the dataframe
df['RANKING'] = rank_col
```

Note: This will give you the score, not just the rank. For example, with three cities the output would be (fake data):

| index | Date | City | QTDPERCAPITA | RANKING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01 | Los Angeles | 0.02 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2020-02 | Los Angeles | 0.025 | 0.33 |
| 2 | 2020-03 | Los Angeles | 0.027 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 2020-01 | Houston | 0.05 | 1.0 |
| 4 | 2020-02 | Houston | 0.033 | 1.0 |
| 5 | 2020-03 | Houston | 0.066 | 1.0 |
| 6 | 2020-01 | Denver | 0.03 | 0.33 |
| 7 | 2020-02 | Denver | 0.021 | 0.0 |
| 8 | 2020-03 | Denver | 0.056 | 0.74 |

With Corralien's answer, it will give you true normalized rankings:

| index | Date | City | QTDPERCAPITA | RANKING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01 | Los Angeles | 0.02 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2020-02 | Los Angeles | 0.025 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 2020-03 | Los Angeles | 0.027 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 2020-01 | Houston | 0.05 | 1.0 |
| 4 | 2020-02 | Houston | 0.033 | 1.0 |
| 5 | 2020-03 | Houston | 0.066 | 1.0 |
| 6 | 2020-01 | Denver | 0.03 | 0.5 |
| 7 | 2020-02 | Denver | 0.021 | 0.0 |
| 8 | 2020-03 | Denver | 0.056 | 0.5 |